# How to get WP_User object or usermeta from another Wordpress site?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Is there a way to retrieve the `WP_User` object from a separate Wordpress installation ?

I'm trying to display a list of users from another Wordpress site. I don't necessarily want the new Wordpress site to share the same users, I just need to display a list of the older websites users alongside select usermeta data: `first_name`, `last_name` and some custom meta fields such as their position in the company and which office they work at.

I have managed to connect to the other Wordpress site's database via the following snippet:

```
$newdb = new wpdb($DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD, $DB_NAME, $DB_HOST);
$newdb->set_prefix('wp_');
```

However, when I try to use the following query, I don't get any results, or I get MySQL syntax error messages:

```
$users = $newdb->get_col( $newdb->prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM $newdb->users ORDER BY %s ASC", $sort )
);
```

When I use this query, I get results:

```
$users = $newdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_users ORDER BY user_nicename ASC");
```

But I cannot use `get_userdata()` to retrieve the `WP_User` object.

Comment: Do the two installations share a database?

Comment: No, they do not currently share a database. The older site has also been in use for several years. (The site where I'm trying to pull the data in is a brand new website.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress installations by default cannot talk to each other - they are scoped to their own database or database tables and are not meant to interact in that fashion. If you're simply trying to get a list of users in a different database, you should do a standard MySQL query outside the wordpress framework.